# What is $\iint_R dy\,dx$ calculating exactly?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Also, $R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (0 \le x \le 4) \land (0 \le y\le\sqrt{x})\}$

If $ z = f(x,y) = 1$, I get this:

[image]

The domain of integration is this:

[image]

Is this what I am calculating the volume of? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the volume of a solid of height 1 above the domain, so yes, I think your picture is correct. Of course the volume of a solid of height 1 above a region is also the area of the region, if all three length units are the same.